# How do I install the video driver for my Toshiba Satellite on 14.04?

Tags: drivers, ati

I'm having lag in images and movies that I didn't in Windows. I think this might be a driver issue, what driver do I need to install, and how do I do it?

My laptop is **Toshiba satellite** with **Ati xpress 200m**.

Comment: That is ok I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Software Sources" from "System Settings", there should be a tab called "Additional Drivers". Look for proprietary drivers for your graphic card

Comment: Hi ed0,
Thanks for your comment but I can't find software sources from system settings. And I'm just wondering what should I do with that information that you are asking me to look for?

Comment: Reading your question, of it actually is a driver issue, then it should be a driver for your pc's graphic card (this is what I understood, tell me if I'm wrong :) . If it's so, you have to install the proprietary driver from "Additional Drivers" (since by default you're using an open source one.

Comment: You can try to search Software Sources right from the Dash, but I can't figure out the translation to your mothertongue

Comment: try instead to look for Software and UPDATES (in your language, of course)